# Program randomly terminates after executing toUpperCase method in Java

Tags: java, methods, system

My Java program terminates after using the `System.out.println();`

I have put `System.out.println` in a few places in my code to find out exactly where it is terminating and it seems to be terminating right after it executes the `println`

```
package exercises;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrainSeatBookingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SeatType theSeatType;
        FloorGrid floorType;
        TrainWay aTrainWay = null;
        TrainSmart aTrainSmart = null;
        Seat customerSeat;
        char planeSizeChoice;
        char seatingArea;
        char seatEconomyOrFirst;
        char programBookingChoice;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to board a petite floor sized plane or a grande floor sized plane?");
        planeSizeChoice = scan.next().charAt(0);
        planeSizeChoice = Character.toUpperCase(planeSizeChoice);
        if (planeSizeChoice == 'P') {
            floorType = new PetiteFloorGrid();
            floorType.initialiseFloorGrid();
            System.out.println("Would you like to be in the middle, window or asile?");
            seatingArea= scan.next().charAt(0);
            seatingArea = Character.toUpperCase(seatingArea);
            System.out.println("Would you like to be seated in first class or middle class?");
            seatEconomyOrFirst = scan.next().charAt(0);
            seatEconomyOrFirst = Character.toUpperCase(seatingArea);
            System.out.println("Would you like your seat to be booked via the smart program or the way program?");
            programBookingChoice = scan.next().charAt(0);
            programBookingChoice = Character.toUpperCase(programBookingChoice);
            if (seatEconomyOrFirst == 'F') {
                    if (programBookingChoice == 'S') {
                        customerSeat =  aTrainSmart.reserveFirstClass(planeSizeChoice, SeatType.MIDDLE);
                        System.out.println(floorType);
                    }
                    else {
                        customerSeat =  aTrainWay.reserveFirstClass(planeSizeChoice, SeatType.MIDDLE);
                        System.out.println(floorType);
                    }
                }
            }
        else {
            floorType = new GrandeFloorGrid();
            floorType.initialiseFloorGrid();
            System.out.println("Would you like to be in the middle, window or asile?");
            seatingArea= scan.next().charAt(0);
            seatingArea = Character.toUpperCase(seatingArea);
            System.out.println("Would you like to be seated in first class or middle class?");
            seatEconomyOrFirst = scan.next().charAt(0);
            seatEconomyOrFirst = Character.toUpperCase(seatingArea);
            System.out.println("Would you like your seat to be booked via the smart program or the way program?");
            programBookingChoice = scan.next().charAt(0);
            programBookingChoice = Character.toUpperCase(programBookingChoice);
            System.out.println("Did not reach start of if");//testing program LINE57
            if (seatEconomyOrFirst == 'F') {
                if (programBookingChoice == 'S') {
                    customerSeat =  aTrainSmart.reserveFirstClass(planeSizeChoice, SeatType.MIDDLE);
                    System.out.println(floorType);
                }
                else {
                    customerSeat =  aTrainWay.reserveFirstClass(planeSizeChoice, SeatType.MIDDLE);
                    System.out.println(floorType);
                }
                //System.out.println("Did not go through either if or else");//testing program
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have 2 other lines that do the exact same (but save to different variables) and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: The three lines of code you have posted are insufficient to diagnose possible causes of your problem. Post more code. Try your debugger.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will edit it and add the class.

Comment: Added the whole class

Comment: Also share the input you are providing for scan

Comment: There are a whole lot of `println` statements there. Which one is *the* `println` you're talking about?

Comment: I just simply put s in the input for the scan

Comment: The one with the comment "//testing program LINE57" above the if statement. I did add that but someone edited it out when making the spacing look nice.

Comment: @ExileVoid No, not the only input, I've asked about all the input you are providing throughout the program, there are lot of scan statement

Comment: Would you like to board a petite floor sized plane or a grande floor sized plane?
g
Would you like to be in the middle, window or asile?
m
Would you like to be seated in first class or middle class?
f
Would you like your seat to be booked via the smart program or the way program?
s

Comment: That is exactly what I put, copied from console.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. The part which you violate is **minimal**. I bet the error can be reproduced by a single statement.

Comment: Someone asked for more code, so I gave more code

Comment: @ExileVoid, I understand. Of course, having complete and non-minimal code is better than having non-complete and minimal code. However, what you *should* have is code which is *both* complete and minimal. There are multiple reasons for that, one of them is that you would have likely found the error yourself.

Comment: For some reason now my "planeSizeChoice = Character.toLowerCase(scan.next().charAt(0));" will read input but after pressing enter it just stays like that and does not do anything else. Almost like its constantly waiting for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
seatEconomyOrFirst = scan.next().charAt(0);
seatEconomyOrFirst = Character.toUpperCase(seatingArea);
```

should be

```
seatEconomyOrFirst = scan.next().charAt(0);
seatEconomyOrFirst = Character.toUpperCase(seatEconomyOrFirst);
```

You are ignoring the read character and re-using `seatingArea`. That method of updating character to upper case appears to be an anti-pattern. You could do it in one line. Like,

```
seatEconomyOrFirst = Character.toUpperCase(scan.next().charAt(0));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it. Will be useful knowing that is the better way to do it! Should I delete this thread as it was merely a mistake or?

Comment: For some reason now my  "planeSizeChoice = Character.toLowerCase(scan.next().charAt(0));" will read input but after pressing enter it just stays like that and does not do anything else. Almost like its constantly waiting for input.